# Hidden/visible accroding to the value of a field of that row

Tags: asp.net

I hope a button of a row, I hope the value of "MyColumn" is "ValueA", the button is visible, otherwise no.
My code is as followed:

```
style="visibility: '<%# (Eval("MyColumn").ToString()) =="ValueA"? "visible" : "hidden" %>'
```

But I find my code does not function?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like below button tag in asp.net webform

```
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" Visible='<%# (Eval("MyColumn").ToString()) =="ValueA" %>'   runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MyColumn") %>'></asp:Button>
```